# c3p0 connection checkout taking 15 minutes to fail at times

Tags: oracle, connection-pooling, c3p0

hit a problem using c3p0. In most cases works fine, but in prod env behind firewalls ocasionally fails to checkout connection. The problem is that it takes it 15 minutes to recognize connection is not usable. The pool is not exausted as other connection are being checked out and used happily during that 15 minute inteval.

logs:

```
23 Apr 2015 09:08:16.426 [EventProcessor-1] DEBUG c.m.v.c.i.C3P0PooledConnectionPool - Testing PooledConnection [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@5a886282] on CHECKOUT.
```

15 minutes later:

```
23 Apr 2015 09:23:43.073 [EventProcessor-1] DEBUG c.m.v.c.i.C3P0PooledConnectionPool - Test of PooledConnection [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@5a886282] on CHECKOUT has FAILED. 
java.sql.SQLException: Connection is invalid
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.testPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:572) [c3p0-0.9.5.jar:0.9.5]
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.finerLoggingTestPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:451) [c3p0-0.9.5.jar:0.9.5]
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.finerLoggingTestPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:443) [c3p0-0.9.5.jar:0.9.5]
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.refurbishResourceOnCheckout(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:336) [c3p0-0.9.5.jar:0.9.5]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.attemptRefurbishResourceOnCheckout(BasicResourcePool.java:1727) [c3p0-0.9.5.jar:0.9.5]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:553) [c3p0-0.9.5.jar:0.9.5]
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutAndMarkConnectionInUse(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:756) [c3p0-0.9.5.jar:0.9.5]
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:683) [c3p0-0.9.5.jar:0.9.5]
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:140) [c3p0-0.9.5.jar:0.9.5]
```

and then some more logs:

```
23 Apr 2015 09:23:43.073 [EventProcessor-1] DEBUG c.m.v.r.BasicResourcePool - A resource could not be refurbished for checkout. [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@5a886282] 
java.sql.SQLException: Connection is invalid
...
23 Apr 2015 09:23:43.074 [EventProcessor-1] DEBUG c.m.v.r.BasicResourcePool - Resource [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@5a886282] could not be refurbished in preparation for checkout. Will try to find a better resource. 
23 Apr 2015 09:23:43.074 [C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->67oy4j981qzvkd716hgow4|4177fc5c]-HelperThread-#2] DEBUG c.m.v.r.BasicResourcePool - Preparing to destroy resource: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@5a886282 
23 Apr 2015 09:23:43.074 [EventProcessor-1] DEBUG c.m.v.c.i.C3P0PooledConnectionPool - Testing PooledConnection [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@41318736] on CHECKOUT. 
23 Apr 2015 09:23:43.074 [C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->67oy4j981qzvkd716hgow4|4177fc5c]-HelperThread-#2] DEBUG c.m.v.c.i.C3P0PooledConnectionPool - Preparing to destroy PooledConnection: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@5a886282 
23 Apr 2015 09:23:43.076 [C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->67oy4j981qzvkd716hgow4|4177fc5c]-HelperThread-#2] DEBUG c.m.v.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection - Failed to close physical Connection: oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@25145762 
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Broken pipe
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logoff(T4CConnection.java:612) ~[ojdbc6_g-11.2.0.1.0.jar:11.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.close(PhysicalConnection.java:5094) ~[ojdbc6_g-11.2.0.1.0.jar:11.2.0.1.0]
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection.close(NewPooledConnection.java:642) [c3p0-0.9.5.jar:0.9.5]
```

c3p0 Configuration:

```
        ComboPooledDataSource ods = new ComboPooledDataSource();
...
        ods.setInitialPoolSize(5);
        ods.setMinPoolSize(5);
        ods.setMaxPoolSize(10);
        ods.setMaxStatements(50);

        ods.setTestConnectionOnCheckout(true);
```

So nothing too exotic. I know connection loss is possible, hence testing connection on checkout. Any ideas why it is taking so long to verify/fail connection? We are using Oracle database. 
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like it is a situation when connection is terminated by a firewall in a way that there is no response sent back at all, even a TCP ACK without data. In this case query to verify a connection will never return. This is on socket/jdbc driver level.

Solution:

- find out firewall disconnect policy (in our case 1 hour)
- set **c3p0.maxConnectionAge** property to force c3p0 reconnect connections every X seconds.

Answer (score 2):

First, I presume you've verified that there are no checkouts of that Connection in between your log messages. Obviously, you'd expect lots of messages like...

```
Testing PooledConnection [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@5a886282] on CHECKOUT.
```

...before the final message just prior to the failure. Lots of those messages would occur much earlier. Only the final message just prior to the failure should, ideally, be much closer to detection of the failure than the 15 mins that you are seeing.

Assuming that is the final message like that, then the issue has to do with how your Connections die. c3p0 runs a test, and then waits for either successful completion or an Exception. If your Connection dies in a way such that the Connection test merely hangs for 15 mins, well, then you might see what you are seeing.

Here are a few suggestions.

1. Use c3p0's [idleConnectionTestPeriod](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#idleConnectionTestPeriod) to detect these failures ideally prior to client checkouts, so that clients are less likely experience long hangs. (You might test on check-in as well.)
2. Figure out what kind of Connection test is getting run. You are using c3p0 0.9.5, so if your driver supports it, the default test is a call to Connection.isValid(), which should be fast. I don't see in any of the log you've quoted a stack trace of the actual test failure (Perhaps it is a truncated root cause Exception? It would definitely be logged at FINER/DEBUG level by a logger called `com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool`) Verify (from the stack trace) that your driver is using a fast `isValid()` Connection test rather tha c3p0's slow default Connection test. If it is not (presumably because your driver doesn't support that), then consider setting a fast `preferredTestQuery`.
3. You could try [maxAdministrativeTaskTime](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#maxAdministrativeTaskTime), but that is only likely to really help if whatever is hanging the Connection test responds to an interrupt() call.

Anyway, I hope this isn't entirely useless!

Comment: Hi Steve, thanks for your answer. some of these options would help but I think I now understand actual issue - firewall dropping connections in a way it stops responding at all. I'll provide a separate answer with solution that worked.